# javaws crashes with no output when launching a JNLP application on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, java, java-web-start

I have a JNLP application downloaded. I have installed JRE Version 7 Update 7 from Oracle. I am running Windows 7.

When I double click the JNLP file, I see `javaws` start running in the process list. It dies a few seconds later. While it's running there is a small blue spinning circle animation next to the mouse cursor. Besides the spinning circle, there is no graphical indication that `javaws` was started or killed. There is no error message.

Are there any known reasons for why this could happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reinstall java 7 update 5 or j6u37. It's a bug with jnlp 1.5 spec.
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7191616